# create matrix using regular for loop in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to write the following list comprehension as standard `for` loop. The List comprehension creates a list of lists that can be printed as matrix.

```
matrix = [[col for col in range(5)] for row in range(5)]
```

But I can't get it right to achieve this result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How would the regular for loop look like?

merci A

Comment: your list comprehension seems correct, why do you think it is not giving expected result?

Comment: no, its giving the correct result, I just wanted to recreate it as regular loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unroll all of those list comprehensions, you get something like

```
matrix = []
for row in range(5):
   line = []
   for col in range(5):
       line.append(col)
   matrix.append(line)
```

Comment: merci, that was quick.